# Which UI Design Framework to use for designing and ERP Web Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am actually trying to design an ERP web application, currently working with Angular Material, but seems each input element takes a lot of space(vertical height) on the page, so if I have have 15 input element then I have to scroll down to see and fill. Loved Angular Material but want to try something similar which is free(of course) and best compatibility with angularjs.
Thanks.

Comment: You should read the layout documentation [here] (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction) it definitely explains well enough how you can fit in elements on different screen sizes etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use St table with pagination so that your view is broken into multiple pages, or create your own pagination as well.

It is best practice to make lesser bindings/watchers per page.

Comment: You mean to say, create a pagination concept with page numbers at the bottom to navigate to page. I am talking about if I create a form which has around 15 input elements then its occupying lot of space on the screen.